# C++ - Too Many Include Files? & Struct Redefinition?

Tags: c++, tokenize

I am currently writing a token recognizer for XML. I am going along the basis of FSA's to do so. So I have a Header file that has the following code...

```
#define MAX_LENGTH    512
#define  MAX_NAME  25

struct token 
{
  char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
  int type;
  unsigned char str[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
 };

 #define TOKEN_TYPES 8

 #define SPACES  0
 #define NEWLINE  1
 #define WORD  2
 #define BEGINTAG  3
 #define ENDTAG  4
 #define EMPTYTAG 5
 #define ERROR 6
 #define ENDFILE 7
```

With this I am getting the error:

```
error C2011: 'token' : 'struct' type redefinition
```

I am also getting another strange error in my `gettoken.cpp` file. Where I actually implement the FSA. The File is far to long to display the entire contents. But with this I am getting the error...

```
error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024
```

And here is part of the code for that .cpp file. I will only include my imports in this.

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string>
#include  "Token.h"

using namespace std;
```

I am sure it is something silly as it usually is for me. But please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: have you added include guards to your headers?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `std::string`? And an `enum`? Or constants instead of `#define`'s at the *least*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're somehow including your header file twice. Do you have a guard against that? Every header file should have this:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

[your header file code]

#endif
```

If that's not it, make sure you're not defining token twice somewhere else.

Comment: wow I'm such an idiot. I had my include guards but when I copied and pasted into Visual Studio I left them out by accident! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and getting into include file recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to every header file:

```
#pragma once
```

Comment: Why add a non-standard line to every header file?

Comment: Why add random strings repeated in 3 lines to every header file? You call it non-standard, but every compiler supports it fine.

Comment: It's still non-standard. (Not that that matters to a lot of people)

Comment: Not to mention that `pragma once` increases compilation speed, which is pretty important when it already takes hours to compiler large projects.